# How to set setMaxPerRoute in PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager?

Tags: java, connection-pooling, apache-httpclient-4.x

I have `PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager` where I want to set max connections per route. I'm doing it in next way:

```
poolingHttpClientConnectionManager.setDefaultMaxPerRoute(5);
poolingHttpClientConnectionManager.setMaxPerRoute(new HttpRoute(HttpHost.create(url)), 3);
```

where for example my `url` is `https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2`.
So I have default max per route 5 and 3 per specific url. Then if I call

```
poolingHttpClientConnectionManager.getStats(new HttpRoute(HttpHost.create(url)));
```

I receive as a result `PoolStats` with `max = 3` so everything ok for now.

But when I create a client with pooling connection manager and call same url I can see in logs:

```
PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager - Connection leased: [id: 0][route: {s}->https://repo.maven.apache.org:443][total kept alive: 0; route allocated: 1 of 5; total allocated: 1 of 200]
```

As I can see it still uses 5 connections as max for that example url.
So my question is how to set max connections per some route to make it work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok I've managed to fix it with next code:

```
// code to create HttpRoute the same as in apache library
private HttpRoute getHttpRouteForUrl(String url) throws URISyntaxException
{
    URI uri = new URI(url);
    boolean secure = uri.getScheme().equalsIgnoreCase("https");
    int port = uri.getPort();
    if (uri.getPort() > 0)
    {
        port = uri.getPort();
    }
    else if (uri.getScheme().equalsIgnoreCase("https"))
    {
        port = 443;
    }
    else if (uri.getScheme().equalsIgnoreCase("http"))
    {
        port = 80;
    }
    else
    {
        LOGGER.warn("Unknown port of uri %s", repository);
    }
    HttpHost httpHost = new HttpHost(uri.getHost(), port, uri.getScheme());
    // TODO check whether we need this InetAddress as second param
    return new HttpRoute(httpHost, null, secure);
}
```

And if we use this `HttpRoute` for `setMaxPerRoute` everything works as expected.